# Angular switch statement to do different actions depending on response code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, response

I have a Angular post to node, Depending on the response code I would like to perform a different task.

In my node I have res.send to send back different response codes depending on the action Node side.

I have a small if else statement but it only seems to run the 200 response code it dose not print the 400 or other codes

**my code**

```
FirstModule.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.LoginForm = function() {
        var data = {
            LoginEmail: $scope.sometext.LoginEmail
        };
        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/back-end/controller',
            method: "POST",
            data: data,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 200) $scope.sometext = "200 all good";
            else if (response.status === 400) $scope.sometext = "400 nope";
            else if (response.status === 404) $scope.sometext = "404";
            else if (response.status === 500) $scope.sometext = "500";
            else $scope.sometext = "no data";
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: `response.status` will contain the response code returned by your server. Use `if..else` if there are 2 or 3 of them. Or use `switch`. It's upto you.

Comment: There is 500, 404, 400 and 200 so I was thinking a switch, thanks for your advice ill try to get this working

Comment: 200 will come back in the success. 400,404,500 etc will come back in the fail part of your `then`

Comment: yeah ok thanks ill work on this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way of handling error codes is using Interceptors.

```
app.factory('appInterceptor', function($rootScope, $location, URL, $q) {
    var numLoadings = 0;
    return {
        request: function(config) {
            config.timeout = 15000;
            numLoadings++;
            $rootScope.loading = true;
            $rootScope.noScroll = true;
            return config || $q.when(config)
        },
        response: function(config) {
            if ((--numLoadings) === 0) {
                $rootScope.loading = false;
                $rootScope.noScroll = false;
            }
            return config || $q.when(response);
        },
        requestError: function(config) {
            $rootScope.loading = false;
            $rootScope.noScroll = false;
            return config;
        },
        responseError: function(config) {
            if (!(--numLoadings)) {
                $rootScope.loading = false;
                $rootScope.noScroll = false;
            }
            //based on status, set up your error dialog boxes or messages
            switch (config.status) {
                case 500, 501, 502, 503, 504:
                    $rootScope.servererror = URL.getURL().baseURL + 'partials/modals/server-error.html';
                    break;
                case 400:
                    $rootScope.errorModalMessage = "The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax";
                    $rootScope.errorModalPath = URL.getURL().baseURL + 'partials/modals/error-log.html';
                    break;
                    //Unauthorised Access
                case 401:
                    window.open(URL.getURL().baseURL + 'login', "_self");
                    window.open($rootScope.loginPathUrl, "_self");
                    break;
                case 404:
                    $rootScope.errorModalMessage = "No Data found";
                    $rootScope.errorModalPath = URL.getURL().baseURL + 'partials/modals/error-log.html';
                    break;
                case -1:
                    $rootScope.errorModalPath = URL.getURL().baseURL + 'partials/modals/timeout.html';
                    break;
                default:
            }
            return $q.reject(config);
        }
    }
});
```

You also have to inject your interceptor in your config using `$httpProvider`

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, $urlRouterProvider, URL) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('appInterceptor');
});
```

For purposes of ***global error handling, authentication, or any kind of synchronous or asynchronous pre-processing of request or postprocessing of responses, it is desirable to be able to intercept requests before they are handed to the server and responses before they are handed over to the application code that initiated these requests***. The interceptors leverage the promise APIs to fulfill this need for both synchronous and asynchronous pre-processing.

For more details: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Your code is not working because you are checking for other error codes inside your success. All status codes apart from the 200 success comes in the catch part.

```
$http({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/back-end/controller',
  method: "POST",
  data: data,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 200) $scope.sometext = "200 all good";
}).catch(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 400) $scope.sometext = "400 nope";
  else if (response.status === 404) $scope.sometext = "404";
  else if (response.status === 500) $scope.sometext = "500";
  else $scope.sometext = "no data";
});
```

Comment: It is obvious that this is the best way as it will reduce your line of code across the application for various needs like global error handling, authentication, or even for showing a image loader while waiting for an API call to finish

Comment: You colud do that more performant. You could code that way more readable and so maintainable.(e.g. not using hard coded values for HTTP-Errors) You could write that in a way it supports multiple languages so it is __by far not the best solution__ *But I agree with the advantages you provide*

Comment: What do you want me to do? You want me to write the answer in a better way? I have written it decently from my perspective. If you want to improve my answer, please feel free to. I can't explain all the things in detail because it is a wide topic. That is why I have given the link for reference.

Comment: Looks good, but ill have to look into how to integrate this with my current code base. I have updated my question with updates code

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, Ill look into the switch method as it seems more comprehensive